# SQLAlchemy Oracle - InvalidRequestError: could not retrieve isolation level

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, kedro

I am having problems accessing tables in an Oracle database over a SQLAlchemy connection. Specifically, I am using Kedro `catalog.load('table_name')` and getting the error message `Table table_name not found`. So I decided to test my connection using the method listed in this answer: [How to verify SqlAlchemy engine object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887344/how-to-verify-sqlalchemy-engine-object).

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/?service_name=SERVICE_NAME')
engine.connect()
```

Error: `InvalidRequestError: could not retrieve isolation level`

I have tried explicitly adding an isolation level as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels-including-dbapi-autocommit) like this:

```
engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/?service_name=SERVICE_NAME', execution_options={'isolation_level': 'AUTOCOMMIT'})
```

and this:

```
engine.connect().execution_options(isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT')
```

and this:

```
connection = engine.connect()
connection = connection.execution_options(
    isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"
)
```

but I get the same error in all cases.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest SQL Alchemy.  There were some recent changes in it regarding isolation level and Oracle.

Comment: hey there -  the error you are seeing may occur upon connect() in SQLAlchemy 1.3.21 only.  in 1.3.22, the error above is internally captured and not raised upon connect(); you would only see it if you called the get_isolation_level() method explicitly.  if you are seeing this error with 1.3.22 or above, please post the complete stack trace preferably at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues)

Comment: Thanks @zzzeek updating SQLAlchemy solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from SqlAlchemy 1.3.21 to 1.3.22 solved the problem.