# SQLAlchemy listen to connection/disconnection events

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**TL;DR**: Is it possible to listen to events of DB Connect and Disconnect with SQLAlchemy ORM

### **Background:**

I have a Flask app that connects to a Postgres DB using [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) ORM. ([Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/)). Everything works well, there are no bugs with the below code

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<db>'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Due to network issues, the connection to the DB fails or drop. Which generates errors when DB is accessed. By design
SQLAlchemy handles all connections under the hood, and it is seamless when the connection drops and re-establishment are handled.

### **Requirement**

To monitor and handle these connection drops, I need events triggered for connect and disconnect

Reading through docs I found [`connect`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#modifying-the-dbapi-connection-after-connect-or-running-commands-after-connect), [`close`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.close) and [`engine_connect`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.engine_connect) events that can be tied to the engine

```py
def connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    print('DB Connected')


def disconnect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    print('DB Disconnected')


event.listen(db.engine, 'connect', connect)
event.listen(db.engine, 'engine_connect', connect)
event.listen(db.engine, 'close', connect)
```

Similarly, there are other events like `close_detached` `first_connect` etc.

Note that SQLAlchemy establishes a somewhat "lazy connection" i.e. only when a call to the DB
is made for the first time will the actual connection be established hence `db.engine.connect()`
needs to be called for the `connect` events to fire.

##### Expected Behaviour

1. Whenever a connection to the DB is established whether at the start of the application or during the
   lifecycle. The callback function `connect()` should be fired
2. Whenever a connection is lost due to DB going down or a network issue, the callback function `disconnect()` should be fired

##### Current Behaviour

1. On establishing a connection the first time `connect()` is called. No matter if the connection goes down and connects back `connect()` is not called again
2. On loss of connection `disconnect()` is never called, I might be listening to the wrong event possibly.

For testing, I have PG Server installed locally, I am starting and stopping the service. And verifying the connection using `psql` cli

---

#### Question

I have looked into SQLAlchemy Core to find the appropriate [events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#) and polling mechanism
but have not found anything yet that works.

SQLAlchemy does not look at the connection when not in use, hence polling seems to be required. Does that mean
I need to run a query every n seconds as `db.connection()` does not throw an error in my case when the connection
is lost midway.

I understand the limitations of Flask running in a single process, not supporting async calls intrinsically.
I would like to know how to achieve it even if it were not Flask, what kind of polling would be required

I am not ready to accept that a tool as mature as SQLAlchemy does not support this, but I spent a few days and have not found
a working solution yet. Any help or direction is appreciated.

**Bonus Question:**

What would be the appropriate way to check if the connection to DB is alive on Flask startup.
Currently, I call `db.engine.connect()` after initializing which throws an error if DB is not connected.

Related SO Question: [How to verify SqlAlchemy engine object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887344/how-to-verify-sqlalchemy-engine-object)

More information on how SQLAlchemy Handles Disconnect - [Dealing with Disconnects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html#dealing-with-disconnects)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I am using the connect event of Sqlalchemy to set the [time zone](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/time-zones/#session-time-zone). I can confirm that the connect event works reliably when I manually restart the database. I'm using sqlalchemy 1.3.24 with flask_sqlalchemy 2.5.1 and MariaDB 10.3.17.

My code basically says:

```
app.config.update(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="mysql+pymysql://..."))
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
event.listen(db.engine, 'connect', set_time_zone)
```

If I now start the database, start the application, and perform a request, my connect callback is called. If I restart the database now, the next request will fail (as expected) with:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1927,
> 'Connection was killed')

After that, the next request will call the connect callback again, and the applications works as normal.

The only thing I have to be extremely careful about is that I rollback the session when the OperationalError is raised. If I don't do that, flask needs to be restarted.

So every api endpoint looks like this:

```
def whatever():
    from .. import db
    session = db.session

    try:
        # do your job
    except Exception:
        logger.error("Error: Doing whatever failed")
        print_exc()
        session.rollback()
```

Comment: The behaviour you described is the current behaviour. If you read my expected behaviour, I would like the event to trigger whether I take an action on the DB or not. It's not to throw an error when disconnected and rollback.